# How to use docxj4 in Android project

Tags: java, android, build, docx4j

I want to run `docx4j` on Android. I'm downloaded [this](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/) eclipse project  and extract the `jar` that when I import  into my Android project and run, the application crashed with error message:
 `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.log4j.Logger`. 
Including `log4j` in Android project and app crashed with other errors and etc. Can anyone share how they have been dealt with this problem ?

Comment: What other errors? Please post every occuring error.

Comment: Did you add it to your build path? or post the error which you are getting while crash

Comment: Next error is:
`org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException: Error reading from the stream
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:239)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:213)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.load(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:184)
at test.j.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:26)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Mark has been invalidated.
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.reset(BufferedInputStream.java:329)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:237)`

Answer (score 1):

Try https://github.com/plutext/AndroidDocxToHtml

See further http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/jaxb-can-be-made-to-run-on-android/

http://www.docx4java.org/forums/android-f19/images-t1977.html explains how to use Proguard to keep below the method limit with dex files